# Actionbar HomeButton Image

Tags: smartface.io

In actionbar, I've button to toggle sliderDrawer, home button. But I can't change it's image, it is Smartface Emulator's icon. How can I change it?

P.S: No, **it isn't icon of actionbar**, it is **home button in actionbar**. So this isn't my solution:

```
function Page1_Self_OnShow(e){
    this.actionBar.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
    this.actionBar.icon = "ic_actionbar.png";
    this.actionBar.displayShowTitleEnabled = true;
    this.actionBar.title = "Title";
    this.actionBar.subtitle = "Subtitle";
    this.actionBar.displayHomeAsUpEnabled = false;
    this.actionBar.visible = true;
    this.actionBar.onHomeIconItemSelected = function(e){
        Pages.back();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a sliderdrawer object related to a page, you can only see the icon of sliderDrawer on actionBar. 
There was a problem about changing sliderDrawer's icon, it is fixed and will work in next release. 
Until then, you won't be able to change it's icon.

SliderDrawer's icon normally changes as below :

```
var mySliderDrawer = new SMF.UI.SliderDrawer({
    position : SMF.UI.SliderDrawerPosition.left,
    icon : "myicon.png"    //icon property
});
```

This code block will work with the next release of Smartface App Studio.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but as I said, I need to change home button's icon. So, I must wait for next release.